# How to use if expression in Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I want to use `Promise.all()` to handle two promise object, but the second is inner a `if` expression. How to handle this situation?

It looks like this:

```
functionA(); 

if(true) {
    functionB(); 
}
```

`functionA()` and `functionB()` both return a promise object. In normal case, I could use

```
Promise.all([
    functionA(),
    functionB()
]).then(resule => {
    console.log(result[0]);  // result of functionA
    console.log(result[1]);  // result of functionB
})
```

But how to handle with the `if` expression? Should I wrap the `if(true){functionB()}` in a `new Promise()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you can use `if`s if you use promises as proxies for values, or you can nest the promise one level - personally - I prefer using them as the proxies they are. Allow me to explain:

```
var p1 = functionA();
var p2 = condition ? functionB() : Promise.resolve(); // or empty promise
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(results => {
      // access results here, p2 is undefined if the condition did not hold
});
```

Or similarly:

```
var p1 = functionA();
var p2 = condition ? Promise.all([p1, functionB()]) : p1; 
p2.then(results => {
     // either array with both results or just p1's result.
});
```

Wrapping the conditional in a `new Promise` is [explicit construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) and should be avoided.

Comment: As `Promise.all()` will assimilate *values* as well as promises, that `Promise.resolve()` in the first solution could be a value, which would be an inexpensive way to inject a default value when `functionB()` is not called. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fabup5aq/).

Comment: I agree that calling Promise.resolve() is useless. Pass directly default value e.g. null or undefined. By doc it is valid to pass values instead of promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 4):

```
Promise.all([ cond==true ? p1 : '', p2])
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case i had multiple conditions

```
 functionA(); 
 if(condition1) {
  functionX(); 
 }else if (condition2) {
  functionY(); 
 }....
```

so i did the following

```
const promises = [];
promises.push(functionA());
if (condition1) promises.push(functionX());
else if (condition2) promises.push(functionY());
......

Promise.all(promises).then((results) => console.log('results', results) );
```